# Bubble chart , scatter chart ,candlestick chart using core plot

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics, core-plot

One my ipad project needs to have 8 kinds graph and chart which include 3 variables bubble chart,scatter chart , candlestick chart etc.A quick search gave me result as a core plot which is currently the most used solution for graph and chart in ios.But when i went in there page i didn't see any kind bubble chart or scatter chart implementation. My Question is..

- Is it possible to draw 3 variable bubble chart,scatter chart or candlestick chart in `coreplot`??or i need  to draw the whole graph using core graphics?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Plot natively supports scatter plots and candlestick charts. You can make a bubble chart easily by using custom plot symbols for a scatter plot and varying the size of the plot symbols to represent the third variable.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement only the **scatter chart** here is the code which works well in **swift 3.1 Xcode 8.3.2**

```
func setChart(dataPoints:[String] , value1 :[Double] , value2:[Double])
 {
    var dataEntries1:[ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x:value1[i] , y : Double(i))
        dataEntries1.append(dataEntry)
    }

    var dataEntries2:[ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x:value2[i] , y : Double(i))
        dataEntries2.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let dataSet1 = ScatterChartDataSet(values: dataEntries1, label: "Value1" )
    dataSet1 .setColor(UIColor.blue)
    let dataSet2 = ScatterChartDataSet(values: dataEntries2 ,label: "Value2")
    dataSet2.setColor(UIColor.green)

    var dataSets = [ScatterChartDataSet]()
    dataSets.append(dataSet1)
    dataSets.append(dataSet2)

    let barChartData = ScatterChartData(dataSets: dataSets)

    scatterChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    scatterChart.rightAxis.enabled=false
    scatterChart.legend.enabled=false
    scatterChart.descriptionText = ""
    scatterChart.data = barChartData

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to add **Bubble chart** inside your app

This code works in **Swift 3.1 and Xcode 8.3.2**

```
func setBubbleChart(dataPoints: [Int], values: [Int], amounts: [Int]) {

        var dataEntries: [BubbleChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = BubbleChartDataEntry(x: Double(dataPoints[i]), y: Double(values[i]), size: 15.0)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let format = NumberFormatter()
        format.generatesDecimalNumbers = false
        format.zeroSymbol = ""
        _ = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)

        let chartDataSet = BubbleChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Prashant")
        let chartData = BubbleChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)



        chartDataSet.colors.append(setColor(value:30))

        bubbleChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = true
        bubbleChartView.scaleXEnabled = true
        bubbleChartView.scaleYEnabled = true
        bubbleChartView.highlightPerTapEnabled = true
        bubbleChartView.highlightPerDragEnabled = true

        let firstLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Below 50", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)
        let secondLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Between 50 and 75", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)
        let thirdLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Over 75", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)

        bubbleChartView.chartDescription = nil
        bubbleChartView.legend.entries = [firstLegend, secondLegend, thirdLegend]
        bubbleChartView.data = chartData
        bubbleChartView.drawBordersEnabled = true
        bubbleChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 5.0, yAxisDuration: 5.0)

        let xAxis: XAxis = bubbleChartView.xAxis
        xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
        xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
        xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        xAxis.axisMaximum = 10

        let leftAxis: YAxis = bubbleChartView.leftAxis
        leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
        leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        leftAxis.setLabelCount(2, force: true)
        leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        leftAxis.axisMaximum = 120

        let rightAxis: YAxis = bubbleChartView.rightAxis
        rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    }
```